# Flyway (SpringBoot) migration with file in multiple directories skip version

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, spring-boot, flyway

I am working on a SpringBoot application with Flyway. I have to update the database that already has those migration :

[image]

The migrations under `common` must be executed on different environements (Spring profiles loaded) while `local` and `qa` will have different data inserted into a H2 database.

I need to alter the table (adding and modifying columns) and then update the data inserted in V1_1 and V1_2. I tried MANY different approaches to avoid putting the `ALTER TABLE` sql command in the *local* and *qa* migration files. I would like to leaver the `ALTER TABLE` commands in the *common* folder, while in the *local* and *qa* folder only have the update commands. But all of them were in vain, the new migration I add in the local directory always gets executed before the one I add in the common repository :

[image]

Even with the naming scheme above, V1_4 gets executed before V1_3, causing an error because the new columns were not added yet. I know this is not the perfect naming scheme, I used it mostly for testing and expressing my point. But even while manually testing, flyway does not behave like I would expect (surely because of my misunderstaing). The app log clearly shows V1_3 not being executed :

```
2019-08-13 13:31:04.025  INFO 26508 --- [           main] o.f.core.internal.command.DbMigrate      : Migrating schema "PUBLIC" to version 1.0 - schema
2019-08-13 13:31:04.076  INFO 26508 --- [           main] o.f.core.internal.command.DbMigrate      : Migrating schema "PUBLIC" to version 1.1 - institutions
2019-08-13 13:31:04.092  INFO 26508 --- [           main] o.f.core.internal.command.DbMigrate      : Migrating schema "PUBLIC" to version 1.2 - data
2019-08-13 13:31:04.476  INFO 26508 --- [           main] o.f.core.internal.command.DbMigrate      : Migrating schema "PUBLIC" to version 1.4 - update data
2019-08-13 13:31:04.482 ERROR 26508 --- [           main] o.f.core.internal.command.DbMigrate      : Migration of schema "PUBLIC" to version 1.4 - update data failed! Please restore backups and roll back database and code!
```

I am using this propertiy : `spring.flyway.locations=classpath:db/migration/common,classpath:db/migration/local`
 in the environnement where the exception occurs.

What am I doing wrong ? I can't seem to find a lot of documentation on flyway migration with file in multiple directories. Unfortunatly, this is what I am stuck with and I cannot change the file structure since these decision are out of my hands.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Your 1_3 version is lower case. Most probably it's not seen by Flyway

Answer (score 0):

When you provide a location for your migration, flyway looks for .sql files under that folder and subfolders. So if you have V1.1 and V1.4 in Local and V1.3 in Common, flyway will treat Local as the migration folder and execute in the order V1.1 and V1.4, it won't go to common unless you provide root dir as your flyway location. In your case you should give db.migration as your location.